# Reload tableview realtime in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to reload `tableview` in realtime using `timer`? If viewed, logs are always realtime but in tableview they're not. Is there anything less than my coding?

```
@IBOutlet var tableViewChat: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableViewChat = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), style: UITableViewStyle.plain)

    startTimer()
}

func startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(GetOrders), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timer.fire()
}

func stopTimer() {
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}

func GetOrders() {
    getUserOnline()
    getChatMessage()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableViewChat.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing height of tableview. Now its 0, so I think its not displaying tableview.
As your logs are showing properly, as per my knowledge there should be issue with table view height.

Comment: `tableViewChat` is declared as an `IBOutlet`. So why even create the table in code?

Answer (score 0):

Your tableViewChat is initialised I storyboard so you don't need this line:

```
tableViewChat = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
```

if you want to change the style do it in storyboard.

Also it looks like you are getting the data asynchronous:

```
getUserOnline()
getChatMessage()
```

Which means that it may take some time to have the data back but you reload the table view straight away:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableViewChat.reloadData()
}
```

At that stage you may not have the data at all (so that's why your table view is empty).
You need a completion handler or delegate which fires once the data is downloaded and then reload the table view.

Comment: why I use the coding for the table because if it will not error and at first appear, the data in the table appears all but at the time there is addition of data it does not appear on the table ... my case example is to comment on the video ... on when I comment it the data does not appear labeled but in the log there ...
Well getChatMessage was used to retrieve data by fire on the database.

Comment: I think you must have some other issue in your code if you get error without create another instance of the table view. What you doing here is you have table view created in the storyboard and you override it by creating one programmatically, where do you set up data source and the delegate? You should start by reviewing your code first.